# BULK API2.0 of Salesforce does not update the records when uploading via CSV to the api

Tags: php, salesforce

I am new to Salesforce. I was trying to integrate bulk api 2.0 to one of our internal php application. I was able to upload the csv file to Sales force and process it. But it returns records updated as 0 every time. There is no failures or nothing in the debug log. Can somebody advise what I am doing wrong here?

I hav tried calling the api, passing the same data in the csv as string and it gets updated successfully. Only when I upload the csv itself have problem.

Here is my code:

```
//code for creating the job id

$url = "$instance_url/services/data/v42.0/jobs/ingest";
    $content = json_encode(array("object" => 'Account', "externalIdFieldName" => "Id","contentType"=>'CSV',"operation" => 'update',"lineEnding" => "LF"));

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token",
                    "Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8",
                    "Accept: text/csv"
            ));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);           
            $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);


//code for uploading the csv for bulk update

     $url = "$instance_url/services/data/v42.0/jobs/ingest/7509D0000008eSuQAI/batches";

    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
            array("Authorization: OAuth $access_token",
                    "Content-type: text/csv",
                    "Accept: application/json"

            ));

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");

    $file = "test-3.csv";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file);
    curl_exec($curl);

    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't close the job, SF "thinks" you might want to upload more files. Pass this self-training course: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/api_basics/api_basics_bulk, especially check out the update of `state` field?

Comment: I do update the status as "UpdateComplete". (I have not copied that bit of code here).The status for the job is "Complete". I think it is something to do with the code which post the csv file to SF.